# Sort fetched data by date in ydn db

Tags: ydn-db

I have an issue in ydn db.

I need to fetch records by ids. Because it is not possible yet to say something like 
"WHERE id IN (10, 11, 12)" you have to fetch id to id.

The problem comes here... I do not have to oppurtunity to sort fetched data by date with ydn db.

Now the question: Currently I sort the records with my own algorithm.

Is a indexeddb wrapper out there which is able to fetch records like my example above? If not so, is there a library which sorts an array of objects by given object key? (In my case it would be the date)

Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Not all sorted query are possible in IndexedDB. In this case, you have to resolve to in-memory sorting or using temporary object store. There is incomplete implementation `ydn.db.Buffer` to do this.